# How spring channels are related to queues?

Tags: spring, queue, channel

How spring channels are related to queues?  Are channels always related to queues or these both are separate entity?

I know about queues but how spring channels wrap up queues (if they do)?

Please explain the relationship of channels and queues if exists.

Answer (score 1):

From the [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html):

> The QueueChannel implementation wraps a queue. Unlike the
>   PublishSubscribeChannel, the QueueChannel has point-to-point
>   semantics. In other words, even if the channel has multiple consumers,
>   only one of them should receive any Message sent to that channel. It
>   provides a default no-argument constructor (providing an essentially
>   unbounded capacity of Integer.MAX_VALUE) as well as a constructor that
>   accepts the queue capacity:

However in enterprise integration in general as far as I know channel and queue are synonyms for each other:

> "Channels, also known as queues, are logical pathways that connect the
>   programs and convey messages."

(From [eaipatterns.com](http://www.eaipatterns.com/Introduction.html))